# What kind of bushy plant is this?

Tags: identification, shrubs

I found this bushy plant while walking through an urban area in New England. The majority of its branches were brown, except for the very tips which had a bright red color. It didn't have any flowers, and some of the tips had fallen on the ground which led me to suspect this is how it propagates. I searched online a bit, but I don't think it's a red twig dogwood because the leafs look different.

[image: Found plant]

Comment: Do you have any more photos that show the whole plant? If not, roughly what size was it (height and spread) and did it have a woody base or stem/trunk, like a shrub, or soft stemmed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dogwoods are highly variable in form, but share that characteristic leaf veining (branching off from main vein and curving back in towards the tip) and propagation from stolons and stem tips. Where you find one dogwood generally you find a lot of them in the same area where they spread. This one seems to be Gray Dogwood ([Cornus racemosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornus_racemosa)) which has rather unremarkable stems/twigs in comparison to other dogwoods but has the bright red flower/fruit stalks seen in this photo. Native to NE America.